# Discrepancy between encoding of script file and encoding of read file

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, decoding

I have a .csv file that is encoded in cp1250. I'm assuming that's the case, because when I open the .csv file in Sublime Text, choosing cp1250 is the encoding that lets me view the file with appropriate characters.
Also, the fact that the file is .csv is pretty insignificant, because while it has that extension, the formatting is basically of a regular text file.

**What I want** is to compare lines of the file to some strings I write myself in the script.

First, I had to set the encoding of my .py file, otherwise it would give me
`Non-ASCII character '\x9a' in file C:\Users\lezal\Desktop\convertJournal.py on line 4, but no encoding declared`

So I added `# coding=cp1250` on my second line (First one being `#! python2`), which is the same encoding that the .csv file has.
I open the file with `io` this way:

```py
openedFile = io.open(file, encoding = "cp1250")
allLines = openedFile.readlines()
```

And when I print the particular line, inside the terminal it shows me `Jan Mašek Pekařství s.r.o.`
Which is what I also have in my file, `elif x == "Jan Mašek Pekařství s.r.o. "`

But yet, when I run the elif, I get:

```py
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  elif x == "Jan MaÜek Peka°stvÝ s.r.o. ":
```

I tried converting both .py file and .csv file into utf-8, which gives me the same problem, just with different characters. And I also tried converting the .csv file into .txt, since that's what it effectively is, but the result is the same.

Any advice is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you put an `encoding` on the `open`, you made Python convert all the strings it reads into Unicode.  But you're not comparing to a Unicode string in the `if` so it can't compare them.  Just change the line:

```
elif x == u"Jan Mašek Pekařství s.r.o. ":
```

You should also consider converting to Python 3.

Comment: Sweet, this did it!

...I still had to notice that the .readlines() leaves me with an extra \n at the end though, which is why my comparison always returned False. Big facepalm.

Comment: @Lezalith I think we all make that mistake the first time.